# Where are EC2 manifest files located and how can I access them?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, manifest, amazon-ami

When creating EC2 instances via the AWS Management Console, there are manifest names provided, like

```
amazon-linux-mono-2-10/image.manifest.xml
```

but they are not links.

Could someone point me to the location of the manifests and tell me how I can read the contents? (I know how to use XML, but there seems to be some problems with accessing manifest files).
For example, manifest

```
 amazon/CloudFormation-insoshi_1.0.0_2.0_8e1fece7-64bit-20110727-1654
```

seems to be located at

```
 https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazon/CloudFormation-insoshi_1.0.0_2.0_8e1fece7-64bit-20110727-1654
```

but is inaccessible (AccessDenied)

Comment: you can't read it. As you have found out -- it have another access control. If you can launch it, you may try cloning it live.

Comment: I was thinking about reading configurations of ami's to find if they have installed software I need, like asterisk or something to spare me the trouble of installing it myself

Comment: The manifests don't describe the contents of the image, they describe the files that the image is split into after generation. The info you are looking for isn't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're on Amazon S3 and they're not meant for you; they are just pointers to the machine image files and such EC2 needs to grab to deploy that AMI.